# Power Steering leak

Tags: steering, power

We had -30 this morning, when I went to leave in 08 Ram I had no P.S. and fluid leaking on ground.  I put it into heated shop and refilled resevoir, let sit a couple house and now it works and no apparent leaking?!?  Any suggestions what occurred?

Comment: Seals shrunk.......